# Stored procedure executing and getting 1 row affected but actually in db it is not effecting

Tags: stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[statusupdate]
    (@userid INT, @status BIT)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Users 
    SET @status = IsDeleted
    WHERE @userid = UserId
END
```

I am updating only one column (`IsDeleted`) based on `userid` in the `Users` table. It is executing but not reflecting the change in the database.

Comment: exec statusupdate @userid=4,@status=1        i am getting (1 row(s) affected)   but in db it is not changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write the wrong code!
You need to fix the following.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[statusupdate]
(@userid INT, @status BIT)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Users 
    SET  IsDeleted = @status
    WHERE  UserId = @userid
END
```